# How can I change a date style in R?

Tags: r

A column in my dataset includes dates such as Month Name and Year. I want to change the month's name to number.

My dataset looks like this (but is not limited to only 3 rows):

[image: my dataset looks like this]

I want to change the ldr_start column to this:
ldr_start
3/92
7/93
8/93

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note, in particular, where it says not to use only images but rather to show the data as the result of running `dput` so that others don't have to retype it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input defined reproducibly in the Note at the end we have some alternatives.

**1) yearmmon** Using the test data in the Note at the end convert the input column to yearmon class and then format it in the desired fashion.  See ?strptime for information on the percent codes.

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, start2 = sub("^0", "", format(as.yearmon(start, "%b-%y"), "%m/%y")))
##    start start2
## 1 Mar-92   3/92
```

**1a)** If it is ok to have a leading zero on one digit months then we can omit the `sub` and just write:

```
transform(DF, start2 = format(as.yearmon(start, "%b-%y"), "%m/%y"))
##    start start2
## 1 Mar-92  03/92
```

**2) Base R** Using only base R we can append 1 to `start` to make it a valid date (valid dates require year, month and day and not just month and year) and then proceed in a similar way as in (1) or (1a).

```
transform(DF, 
  start2 = sub("^0", "", format(as.Date(paste(start, 1),  "%b-%y %d"), "%m/%y")))
##    start start2
## 1 Mar-92   3/92
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(start = "Mar-92") # test data frame
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a "date" in either case. The `zoo` package does define a 'yearmon' class whose use in this case has been illustrated by one of that package's authors, @G.Grothendieck.

Here we can just use `strsplit` and process the month-character, match against the R `?Constants`, `month.abb`, and then rejoin:

```
dat <- scan(text="Mar-92,Feb-93,Jul-94,Sep-95", what = "", sep=",")
#Read 4 items
datspl <- strsplit(dat, split="-")
sapply( datspl, function(mnyr){ paste( match(mnyr[1], month.abb), mnyr[2], sep="/")})
#[1] "3/92" "2/93" "7/94" "9/95"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `stringr`'s `str_replace_all`:

```r
data <- c("Mar-92", "Jul-93", "Aug-93")

str_replace_all(data, setNames(as.character(1:12), month.abb))
```

**Output:**

```r
[1] "3-92" "7-93" "8-93"
```

**Update 14/aug: Why this works**

As pointed out by @IRTFM this functionality might be unexpected at first glance. However, it can be found in the documentation for the `replacement`-argument:

> To perform multiple replacements in each element of string, pass a named vector (c(pattern1 = replacement1)) to str_replace_all. Alternatively, pass a function to replacement: it will be called once for each match and its return value will be used to replace the match.

The functionality is also evident in the code. If we pass a named vector, the names get assigned to the 'pattern' argument and the values get assigned to the 'replacement' argument, exactly as expected:

```
if (!is.null(names(pattern))) {
        vec <- FALSE
        replacement <- unname(pattern)
        pattern[] <- names(pattern)
    }
```

Comment: This does work but after reading the documentation I still find it surprising that it does. In the examples it is stated that the named vector is passed to the 'pattern' argument, while in the arguments section that behavior is described in the 'replacement' argument section. Nowhere is it described what will happen when onluy two arguments are offered.Since there is n odefault value described in the usage section for either of those arguments I would have predicted that an error would occur.

Comment: Thanks for adding further clarification. The functionality is somewhat hidden, but can be found in the documentation of the `replacement` argument: **To perform multiple replacements in each element of string, pass a named vector (c(pattern1 = replacement1)) to str_replace_all.**

Comment: :I did see that documentation, but felt the presenting the code clarified the matter better because the named vector argument is NOT being handled as a value given to the 'replacement' parameter but rather to the 'pattern' parameter. It is properly described down in the comments in 'Examples' section. If you give that value to the 'replacement' parameter you WILL get an error about a missing 'pattern' argument.